# Can´t connect to running keycloak docker image in azure container instances

Tags: docker, keycloak, azure-container-instances

`az container create -g mygroup --name myname --image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak  --environment-variables 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD'='password' 'PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING'='true'`

and the instance is running. But how do i start it (run start-dev command) ? When i try to click on connect it takes some seconds and then says connection closed. no errors or events show up.

Comment: you'll have to map the properties to the ACI configuration. This applies to the image name, port,env vars and command. `az container create -g <RGname> --name keycloak1 --image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest --command-line "start-dev --import-realm" --environment-variables 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD'='admin'`

Comment: @Arko thanks for your help, but as soon as the command-line paramter is in it i get: Subscription deployment didn't reach a successful provisioning state after '00:30:00'.

Comment: Benjamin, try this once and let me know if you are able to connect- `az container create -g mygroup --name benjaminkeycloak --image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak  --environment-variables 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD'='password' 'PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING'='true' --ports 8080 8443 --dns-name-label arkokeycloak --ip-address Public` Once created verify- `az container show --resource-group mygroup --name benjaminkeycloak --query "{FQDN:ipAddress.fqdn,ProvisioningState:provisioningState}" --output table`

Comment: Navigate to the Azure portal.
Go to "Container instances" and select the Keycloak container instance you created.
In the container instance overview, you will see the FQDN and IP address. Click on the FQDN or copy it into your browser to access the Keycloak login page.- Kindly check once if you are getting the login page

Comment: @Arko 

ProvisioningState
-------------------
Succeeded

It seems running, but i can´t access it: FQDN: ---, tried the id alone and with:8080 or 8443 but get: This site can’t be reached

In logs everything seems ok: "Keycloak - Open Source Identity and Access Management...

I thought i need to connect to the bash terminal and run start-dev. But that again leads to "connection closed" after some seconds